# I created a sql database and linked with python but while creating an account on running it by the time reach password i get an error mentioned below

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x

When I run the code and create an account when i reach the password part i get the error mentioned below. Please help on resolving the issue.

Error Code

> mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't
> match value count at row 1

Code

```
conn=sql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="password")
c1= conn.cursor()

conn.autocommit=True
s1="create database food"
c1.execute(s1)

if conn.is_connected():
    print("sucessfully connected")

c1.execute('create table myc(cust_name varchar(30),account_no int(50))')
print('myc table created')

c1.execute('create table sales(f_name varchar(30),price float(10),address varchar(100))')
print('sales table created')

import mysql.connector as sql
conn=sql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="password", database="food")
if conn.is_connected():
    print("sucessfully connected")


print("                          ORDER YOUR FOOD HERE")

c1=conn.cursor()
print("1.CREATE YOUR ACCOUNT")
print("2.LOG IN")
print("3.EXIT")
choice=int(input("ENTER YOUR CHOICE:"))
if choice ==1:
    v_cust_name=input("enter your name:")
    v_account_no=int(input("enter your own account number:"))
    v_address=input("enter your address:")
    v_password=(input("enter your password:"))
    v_SQL_insert="insert into myc values('"+v_cust_name+"',"+str(v_account_no)+",'"+v_address+"' ,"+str (v_password)+")"
    c1.execute(v_SQL_insert)
    conn.commit()
    print("ACCOUNT CREATED")
if choice==3:
    print("THANK YOU FOR VISITING")
if choice==2:
    print('')
    print('TO LOGIN FILL THIS DETAILS')
    print('')
    cust_name=input('enter your name')
    print('')
    v_account_no=int(input('enter your accont no'))
    print(' ')
    v_password=int(input('enter your password'))
    print(' ')
    c1=conn.cursor()
    c1.execute('select * from myc')
    data=c1.fetchall()
    count=c1.rowcount
```

Comment: You're trying to insert 4 values into the table `myc`, which has 2 columns...

Comment: BTW: Learn about prepared statements to prevent sql injection

Comment: Seriously can't stress enough. You need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries before you are in the news as the next victim of sql injection.